# Finding the limit of curvature equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, curvature

Given the equation y = $e^x$ and the curvature, $\kappa = e^x/(1+e^{2x})^{3/2}$

(b) Find the $\lim\limits_{x \to\infty} = e^x/(1+e^{2x})^{3/2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{e^x}{(1+e^{2x})^{\frac{3}{2}}} < \frac{e^x}{e^{3x}} = \frac{1}{e^{2x}} \to 0\ \textbf{as} \ x \to \infty$$